# Error in Google Data Studio when using MySQL as data source

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, looker-studio

I encounter the following problem with MySQL in combination with data studio and am frankly quite lost:

```
SELECT 
user.name,
user.second_name,
school.name,
SUM(booked_lessons.duration),
SUM(total_lessons.duration),
SUM(theory_lessons.duration)
FROM
lesson
    LEFT JOIN
user ON lesson.instructor_id = user.id
    LEFT JOIN
school ON lesson.school_id = school.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND lesson.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS booked_lessons ON booked_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = ('driving' OR 'theory' OR 'exam')) AS total_lessons ON total_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'theory') AS theory_lessons ON theory_lessons.id = lesson.id
WHERE
lesson.startDate >= '2018-01-31 00:00:00'
    AND lesson.startDate <= '2019-01-06 23:59:59'
GROUP BY lesson.instructor_id;`
```

When I include import the Code as a MySQL Datasource in Google Data Studio everything seems to work out fine at first.
Yet, when I want to analyze the data in charts I do get the following error message: [Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2meFJ.jpg)

Even more confusing is the following:

when I use this code:

```
`SELECT 
user.name 'Vorname',
user.second_name 'Nachname',
lesson.instructor_id 'FL ID',
school.name 'Standort',
SUM(offered_lessons.duration) 'noch buchbare Praxisstunden',
SUM(booked_lessons.duration) 'gebuchte Praxisstunden',
SUM(total_week_lessons.duration) 'angebotene Praxis gesamt',
SUM(theory_lessons.duration) 'Theorieunterricht',
SUM(exam_lessons.duration) 'Prüfungen',
SUM(total_lessons.duration) 'angebotene Stunden gesamt',
SUM(activity_lessons.duration) 'Sonstige Tätigkeiten',
SUM(canceled_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von 123 <48',
SUM(canceled_48_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von 123 >48',
SUM(canceled_student_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von Schueler <48',
SUM(canceled_48_student_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von Schueler >48',
SUM(canceled_instructor_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von FL <48',
SUM(canceled_48_instructor_lessons.duration) 'abgesagt von FL >48'
FROM
lesson
    LEFT JOIN
user ON lesson.instructor_id = user.id
    LEFT JOIN
school ON lesson.school_id = school.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND lesson.user_id IS NULL) AS offered_lessons ON offered_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND lesson.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS booked_lessons ON booked_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'driving') AS total_week_lessons ON total_week_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = ('driving' OR 'theory' OR 'exam')) AS total_lessons ON total_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'theory') AS theory_lessons ON theory_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'exam') AS exam_lessons ON exam_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id, lesson.duration
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'active'
        AND entity = 'activity') AS activity_lessons ON activity_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) < 48
        AND user_Id != lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_lessons ON canceled_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) >= 48
        AND user_Id != lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_48_lessons ON canceled_48_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) < 48
        AND user_Id = lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_student_lessons ON canceled_student_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) >= 48
        AND user_Id = lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_48_student_lessons ON canceled_48_student_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) < 48
        AND instructor_Id = lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_instructor_lessons ON canceled_instructor_lessons.id = lesson.id
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    lesson.id,
        lesson.duration,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate)
FROM
    lesson
WHERE
    lesson.status = 'canceled'
        AND entity = 'driving'
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, lesson.cancelled_at, lesson.startDate) >= 48
        AND Instructor_Id = lesson.cancelled_by_id) AS canceled_48_instructor_lessons ON canceled_48_instructor_lessons.id = lesson.id
WHERE
lesson.startDate >= '2018-01-31 00:00:00'
    AND lesson.startDate <= '2019-01-06 23:59:59'
GROUP BY lesson.instructor_id;
```

`
The code is almost identical. But now I get this error message:

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGgDp.jpg)

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you check google studio data source connecting with mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
;
) AS t0 GROUP BY Vorname ORDER BY qt_bdgy5cbbub DESC'
```

Do you have a semicolon at the end of a sub query, just before

```
") AS t0"?
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put semicolon (;) at the end of the query, because Datastudio adds code to the query when generating data.
Had the same problem, removed semicolon and now report is working.